# Querying from GAE datastore using count

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

At the moment I am getting the top scores for my Android application from the datastore as follows:

```
     Query query = pm.newQuery(PlayerPersistentData.class);
     query.setOrdering("rating desc");
     query.setRange(0, 25);
```

However, I would also like to order the results by the count of a secondary column:

E.g. In normal SQL it would be something like this:

```
select PlayerPersistentData.*, count(achievements) as achievements_count
from PlayerPersistentData
order by rating desc, achievements_count desc
```

Achievements is defined in the datastore as follows

```
@Persistent
private Set<Integer> achievements;
```

Is this possible using the GAE datastore? And if so how should I create my query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to denormalize: store the count as a separate field on your entity, and query on that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method addSort to your Query object like this:

```
query.addSort("rating", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
query.addSort("achievements", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
```

Comment: Hi, I can give that a whirl but achievements is actually a set. Sorry I should have included that in the original text.     @Persistent
    private Set<Integer> achievements;

Comment: In that case i would use a prepared query, iterate over every result and get the achievement.count from that. see the first code block. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html There are probably more ways then this but my knowledge is also limited.